# If $p$ is prime, show $kn$ mod $p$ cycles through all values $[0, p-1]$, where $k,n$ are integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Let me restate the question in its entirety:

If $p$ is a prime and $n$ is an integer such that $0 < n < p$, show that the infinite sequence ($n\bmod$$p$, $2n\bmod$$p$, $3n\bmod$$p$, ...) cycles through all integer values $[0,p-1]$ in some order, then repeats.

For example, if $n = 2$ and $p = 5$, the sequence is $(2, 4, 1, 3, 0, REPEAT)$

So far, I understand why the sequence would repeat. However, I don't know how to prove that the sequence will go through every integer in $[0, p-1]$. Insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that if $\gcd(k,p) = 1$, then $k$ has a multiplicative inverse mod $p$?  Do you know Bezout's Little Theorem?

Comment: @JavaMan Negative

Comment: Do you know Euclid's Algorithm?  Context would be helpful: where did you find this problem?  What math do you know?

Comment: @JavaMan This was given by my prof. for an introductory discrete mathematics course. For this problem, we need to know the basics of modular arithmetic, maybe equivalence classes? I know the absolute basics about congruence modulo.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reducing modulo $p$, in other words applying the canonical surjection from the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ to its quotient $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_p$, which **is actually a field**. In this field of quotients the class modulo $p$ of $n$ is invertible, as it is non-zero. Multiplication with an invertible element is a bijection on any ring, in other words if:

> $A$ is a ring and $a \in A$ is invertible then the maps of left multiplication $A \rightarrow A, x \mapsto ax$ and right multiplication $A \rightarrow A, x \mapsto xa$ are bijections.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of my course =(

Comment: In more down to earth fashion, define $\rho: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow [0, p-1]$ to be the map sending arbitrary integer $m$ to its remainder mod $p$. Then the map $\varphi: [0, p-1] \rightarrow [0, p-1], \varphi(k)=\rho(kn)$ is an injection from a finite set to itself, hence a surjection as well. One proves it is indeed an injection by applying the following fundamental proposition in number theory: if $m,n, k \in \mathbb{Z}, m|kn$ and $(m, k)=1$ then $m|n$.